# Soapui - Groovy ReplaceAll regex

Tags: regex, groovy, soapui

I have a string (myString) which contains some xml tags such as...

```
<TargetValue>4</TargetValue>
<TargetValue></TargetValue>
<TargetValue>2</TargetValue>
```

I need to replace all the numbers between the tags with a random number I generated using code

```
def myRnd = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10) + 1
```

I have tried all kinds of replaceAll commands but can't seem to get the regex correct as nothing ever gets replaced. Would someone know how to construct the correct replaceAll command to update all the values between the tags

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing XML with regular expressions.  Look into XmlSlurper or XmlParser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
def str = '''<TargetValue>4</TargetValue>
<TargetValue></TargetValue>
<TargetValue>2</TargetValue>
'''

str.replaceAll(/[0-9]+/) {
    Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10) + 1
}
```

**UPDATE**

Then try something like:

```
def str = '''<TargetValue>4</TargetValue>
<TargetValue></TargetValue>
<TargetValue>2</TargetValue>
'''

str.replaceAll(/\<TargetValue\>\d+\<\/TargetValue\>/) {
    '<TargetValue>' + (Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10) + 1) + '</TargetValue>'
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

As @tim_yates suggest it's better to use a `XmlSlurper` than regex, however you need a well formed xml to parse, so in your example your xml need a root node to be well formed. Then you can do the same as you do using regex using `XmlSlurper`:

```
def str = '''<root>
<TargetValue>4</TargetValue>
<TargetValue></TargetValue>
<TargetValue>2</TargetValue>
</root>
'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(str)
xml.'**'.findAll {
    it.name() == 'TargetValue'
}.each {
    it.replaceBody(Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10) + 1)
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

This script logs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <TargetValue>8</TargetValue>
  <TargetValue>3</TargetValue>
  <TargetValue>6</TargetValue>
</root>
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Sorry, I should of been all clear. The XML will also contain other tags which may have numbers so I specifically only want to change the values in the TargetValue tags not every number in xml

Comment: Thanks, very close. It also needs to update the TargetValue tags that don't contain a number

Comment: @user3803807 all <TargetValue> tags despite their content?

Answer (score 0):

> Will this work for you:

```
String ss = "<TargetValue>4</TargetValue>";
int myRnd = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 10) + 1;
String replaceAll = ss.replaceAll("\\<TargetValue\\>\\d+\\</TargetValue+\\>", "<TargetValue>"+myRnd+"</TargetValue>", String.valueOf(myRnd));
System.out.println(replaceAll);
```